# without clicking the open hamburger dropdown how to hide and when I click open

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, react-native

[Hamburger dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKMNs.png)

I want to hide dropdown when I click open then dropdown hamburger  button using CodeIgniter  JavaScript and jQuery    Please someone help me what can I fix and which function I use i am facing this issue last two week.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an HTML structure similar to the following:

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="hamburger-btn">Open</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Here's an example JavaScript code using jQuery that hides the dropdown menu when clicking on the hamburger button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hamburger-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });
});
```

In the above code, we bind a click event handler to the **.hamburger-btn element**. When clicked, it finds the sibling element with the class **.dropdown-menu** and toggles its visibility using the **toggle() function**.

Make sure you have included the jQuery library in your HTML file before using the above code.

If you have further specific issues or error messages, please provide more details, and I'll be happy to assist you further.